# How to specify return type of expression tree?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

If I build an expression tree by hand, the run-time seems to automatically determine the return type. So if I build an expression tree which looks like this:

```
// Order contains a navigation property for Customer
(Order o) => o.Customer;
```

the run-time is determining the return type as Customer, essentially this:

```
Expression<Func<Order, Customer>> efd = (Order o) => o.Customer;
```

How can I build it - or change what I built, so the return is object, i.e. the expression would be:

```
Expression<Func<Order, object>> ef = (Order o) => o.Customer;
```

This is generic and I don't know at compile time that the return type would be Customer; it could be any navigation propery from (in this case) order.

**Clarification**

Let's say I start with an expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<OrderDTO, object>> ef = (OrderDTO o) => o.Customer;
```

I have a routine which is rebuilding this, changing the type of `OrderDTO` to `Order` by walking the tree and changing the types based on a map of from / to types. That's all I'm doing, but the resulting expression is

```
Expression<Func<Order, Customer>> ef = (Order o) => o.Customer;
```

So when I rebuild the tree, I need to specify the return type somehow - it looks as if the system is automatically determining the return type as I didn't specify it anyway. Thanks, Ray

Comment: So, whats wrong with your last expression?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here, are you asking how to change the return type of an existing expression tree? Or are you asking how to format your lambda expressions such that you have control over the return type?

Comment: `(Order o) => (object)o.Customer`?

Comment: Have you tried generics with something like `Func<Order, T> GetLamba<T>(...); `

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your rewrite code?

Comment: The problem with the last expression - is I need to assign it to something of this type: Expression<Func<Order, object>> ef = (Order o) => o.Customer; as that is what the lambda version of .Include() wants. I get a typecast error. Clear? Best Ray

Comment: Nicholas - do you mean to show the code which does the conversion? It's quite long as it involves walking the tree using the visitor etc. Best Ray

Comment: @RBrowning99 ( note: on SO you have to put an @ sign in front of people's names if you want them to be notified of your replies. ) And yes, your visitor code would be useful - or at least an outline of it including the part where you get the rewritten expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without actually seeing your code, but it looks like you're using on of the versions of [`Expression.Lambda()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda.aspx) that don't let you specify the type of the created expression. If you do that, you're right that the delegate type will be decided automatically.

To fix this, you either need to use a version of `Expression.Lambda()` that lets you specify the delegate type using a type parameter (e.g. `Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, object>>(…)`), or, more likely in your case, the version where the delegate type is specified as a normal parameter of type `Type` (`Expression.Lambda(funcType, …)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReturnTypeVisitor<TSource, TReturnValue> : ExpressionVisitor{

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), typeof(TReturnValue));
        return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(TSource))
        {
            return Expression.Property(Visit(node.Expression), node.Member.Name);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Foo{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar { }

Expression<Func<Foo, object>> expression = p => p.Bar;
Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>> stronglyTypedReturnValue =(Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>>) new ReturnTypeVisitor<Foo, Bar>().Visit(expression);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71829408/2936295

Just use `Expression.Convert` on expression body:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TConvertedResult>> ConvertResult<TSource, TResult, TConvertedResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TConvertedResult>>(Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(TConvertedResult)), expression.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExpressionHelperTest
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass(bool boolean)
        {
            Boolean = boolean;
        }

        public bool Boolean { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass(bool boolean, int integer) : base(boolean)
        {
            Integer = integer;
        }

        public int Integer { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ConvertResult_Simple_Test()
    {
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> notNullExpression = i => i != 0;
        Expression<Func<int, object>> notNullObjectResultExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConvertResult<int, bool, object>(notNullExpression);

        Func<int, bool> notNull = notNullExpression.Compile();
        Func<int, object> notNullObjectResult = notNullObjectResultExpression.Compile();

        Assert.True(notNull(1));
        Assert.False(notNull(0));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, notNullObjectResult(1));
        Assert.AreEqual(false, notNullObjectResult(0));

        Assert.Pass();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ConvertResult_Inheritance_Test()
    {
        Expression<Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass>> derivedClassExpression = x => new DerivedClass(x.boolean, x.integer);
        Expression<Func<(bool boolean, int integer), BaseClass>> baseClassExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConvertResult<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass, BaseClass>(derivedClassExpression);
        Expression<Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass>> derivedClassFromBaseClassExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConvertResult<(bool boolean, int integer), BaseClass, DerivedClass>(baseClassExpression);

        Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass> derivedClass = derivedClassExpression.Compile();
        Func<(bool boolean, int integer), BaseClass> baseClass = baseClassExpression.Compile();
        Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass> derivedClassFromBaseClass = derivedClassFromBaseClassExpression.Compile();

        (bool boolean, int integer) trueAndOne = (true, 1);
        (bool boolean, int integer) falseAndZero = (false, 0);

        Assert.True(derivedClass(trueAndOne).Boolean);
        Assert.False(derivedClass(falseAndZero).Boolean);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, derivedClass(trueAndOne).Integer);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, derivedClass(falseAndZero).Integer);

        Assert.True(baseClass(trueAndOne).Boolean);
        Assert.False(baseClass(falseAndZero).Boolean);

        Assert.True(derivedClassFromBaseClass(trueAndOne).Boolean);
        Assert.False(derivedClassFromBaseClass(falseAndZero).Boolean);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, derivedClassFromBaseClass(trueAndOne).Integer);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, derivedClassFromBaseClass(falseAndZero).Integer);

        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```