# Changing the return type of an expression<func<>>

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Say I have an `Expression<Func<T,object>>` is it possible to dynamically change the return type based on a `Type` variable to be something like `Expression<Func<T,int>>`

I have the following class:

```
public class ImportCheck<T> {

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public int? MinLength { get; set; }
    public int? MaxLength { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> AssociatedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<ImportCheck<Contact>>` which I loop through and for each one set a property on the `Contact` object (the properties are all different types). To enable me to set the property of nested objects I need the result type to be the same as the target type.
If all the properties of the contact were say `int` then what I have now would work fine it's the fact that I have a list of different types that is causing me the headache.

This is how I set a sub property:

```
private static Action<M, R> MakeSet<M, R>(Expression<Func<M, R>> fetcherExp) {
            if (fetcherExp.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "This should be a member getter",
                    "fetcherExp");
            }

            //    Input model 
            var model = fetcherExp.Parameters[0];
            //    Input value to set 
            var value = Expression.Variable(typeof(R), "v");
            //    Member access 
            var member = fetcherExp.Body;
            //    We turn the access into an assignation to the input value 
            var assignation = Expression.Assign(member, value);
            //    We wrap the action into a lambda expression with parameters 
            var assignLambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<M, R>>(assignation, model, value);

            return assignLambda.Compile();
        }
```

This is then called like `MakeSet(member)(target,value)` where member is the `Expression<Func<T,object>>` `target` is the object and `value` is the value to set the property to.

Comment: Can you be more detailed in what you're trying to do?  In particular including example code that doesn't quite do what you want?

Comment: Can you show an example of trying to set the sub-property?  In particular, is this explicit case-by-case code, or in some way generalized?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne added some detail about how I set the property. As my expression result is an object this comes through as a UnaryExpression rather than a MemberExpression which is what is causing me issues

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to abstract properties on a C# class to delegate getters and setters that deal with objects, right?  I'm going to hone in on that, rather that deal with the exact question, since I suspect it's more useful (and much easier to do).

Answer (score 7):

Please find the example below:

```
public class ReturnTypeVisitor<TSource, TReturnValue> : ExpressionVisitor{

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), typeof(TReturnValue));
        return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(TSource))
        {
            return Expression.Property(Visit(node.Expression), node.Member.Name);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Foo{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar { }

Expression<Func<Foo, object>> expression = p => p.Bar;
Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>> stronglyTypedReturnValue = (Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>>)new ReturnTypeVisitor<Foo, Bar>().Visit(expression);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Expression.Convert` on expression body:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TConvertedResult>> ConvertResult<TSource, TResult, TConvertedResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TConvertedResult>>(Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(TConvertedResult)), expression.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExpressionHelperTest
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public BaseClass(bool boolean)
        {
            Boolean = boolean;
        }

        public bool Boolean { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass(bool boolean, int integer) : base(boolean)
        {
            Integer = integer;
        }

        public int Integer { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ConvertResult_Simple_Test()
    {
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> notNullExpression = i => i != 0;
        Expression<Func<int, object>> notNullObjectResultExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConvertResult<int, bool, object>(notNullExpression);

        Func<int, bool> notNull = notNullExpression.Compile();
        Func<int, object> notNullObjectResult = notNullObjectResultExpression.Compile();

        Assert.True(notNull(1));
        Assert.False(notNull(0));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, notNullObjectResult(1));
        Assert.AreEqual(false, notNullObjectResult(0));

        Assert.Pass();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ConvertResult_Inheritance_Test()
    {
        Expression<Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass>> derivedClassExpression = x => new DerivedClass(x.boolean, x.integer);
        Expression<Func<(bool boolean, int integer), BaseClass>> baseClassExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConvertResult<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass, BaseClass>(derivedClassExpression);
        Expression<Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass>> derivedClassFromBaseClassExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConvertResult<(bool boolean, int integer), BaseClass, DerivedClass>(baseClassExpression);

        Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass> derivedClass = derivedClassExpression.Compile();
        Func<(bool boolean, int integer), BaseClass> baseClass = baseClassExpression.Compile();
        Func<(bool boolean, int integer), DerivedClass> derivedClassFromBaseClass = derivedClassFromBaseClassExpression.Compile();

        (bool boolean, int integer) trueAndOne = (true, 1);
        (bool boolean, int integer) falseAndZero = (false, 0);

        Assert.True(derivedClass(trueAndOne).Boolean);
        Assert.False(derivedClass(falseAndZero).Boolean);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, derivedClass(trueAndOne).Integer);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, derivedClass(falseAndZero).Integer);

        Assert.True(baseClass(trueAndOne).Boolean);
        Assert.False(baseClass(falseAndZero).Boolean);

        Assert.True(derivedClassFromBaseClass(trueAndOne).Boolean);
        Assert.False(derivedClassFromBaseClass(falseAndZero).Boolean);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, derivedClassFromBaseClass(trueAndOne).Integer);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, derivedClassFromBaseClass(falseAndZero).Integer);

        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure; you can create a new expression tree with a cast from object to whatever type you want (no guarrantees the cast will hold, of course) - and you can use parts of the old expression tree (namely the entire lambda body) in your new expression tree.

However, even if you create such a thing, note that if you want to express the type of the expresion statically - e.g. `Expression<Func<T,int>>` you're going to need to know the type statically. Generics would work - but a runtime `Type` variable isn't.

There are several problems with your approach:

- You assume that `fetcherExp.Body` is a member access, e.g. `obj.TheProperty`.  However, if the expression is of type `Expression<Func<T,object>>` then any value-type property will be represented as a "Convert(obj.TheProperty)".
- You assume there's a setter corresponding to the getter.
- You assume that the `Type` property is correct.

I suggest you approach this problem differently.  Instead of dealing with improperly typed `Expression<Func<T,object>>` objects and trying to generate setters (and getters?) from that, I suggest you start from an accurately typed `Expression<Func<T,TProperty>>` - or even just a `PropertyInfo` and generate *typed* getters and setters.  Once you have a `Func<T,TProperty> getter` and an `Action<T,TProperty> setter`, you can easily wrap those to generate less specific actions and funcs:

```
public static Action<T,object> UntypeSetter<T,TProperty>(Action<T,TProperty> typedSetter) =>
    (o, val) => typedSetter(o, (TProperty)val);
```

A similar approach is useful for getters (but this only matters for getters of value-type properties since covariance means that reference type getters can all be cast to `Action<T,object>`).

If you absolutely need maximal runtime performance, you can do exactly the same wrapping trick with `Expression<...>`s and inline the nested call to `typedSetter`, but note that you're not winning that much; the difference between one and two delegate calls is unlikely to matter for most applications.

**TL;DR:** Don't use `Expression<Func<T,object>>` as an intermediate representation of an untyped property; doing so throws away type information useful to creating getters/setters.  Instead, use a typed expression `Expression<Func<T,TProperty>>` to easily generate untyped getters and setters, and pass *those* around as your intermediate representation.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to change the return value of an Expression<Func<>> for a very simple case:

```
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> x = t => t > 1;
        
        var prmi = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Invoke(x,prmi), typeof(int)),prmi);

        var i = lambda.Compile().Invoke(2); //returns an int
```