# Cast Expression<Func<Tin, object>> to Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>>

Tags: c#, expression, func, visitor-pattern

I have an `Expression<Func<Tin, object>>` object and I need to cast it to the `Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>>` object.

In fact I have this:

```
x => new <>f__AnonymousType6`1(MyProp = x.MyProp)
```

and I need to have it as:

```
x => new MyType(){MyProp = x.MyProp}
```

Note that I have an `AnonymousType` here!

To achieve this I wrote a function as below:

```
public static Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>> Transform<Tin, Tout>(this Expression<Func<Tin, object>> source)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tout));

    var body = new Visitor<Tout>(param).Visit(source.Body);

    Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tin, Tout>>(body, param);
    return lambda;
}
```

And a Visitor class:

```
class Visitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    ParameterExpression _parameter;

    public Visitor(ParameterExpression parameter)=>_parameter = parameter;

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)=>_parameter;

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.MemberType != System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        var memberName = node.Member.Name;

        var otherMember = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberName);

        var inner = Visit(node.Expression);
        return Expression.Property(inner, otherMember);
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType6`1[System.String]' cannot be used for return type
>   'MyType''

**Update**

In `Tin` and `Tout` classes I have some parametric constructors and a private parameter-less constructor. I **do not want** to use parametric constructors as they have arguments which might be different from the expression required one. I need to build the Expression using private parameter-less constructor.

So if I use the below code:

```
var ctor = typeof(TOut).GetPrivateConstructor();
if (ctor != null) // can replace
     return Expression.New(ctor, node.Arguments);
```

Or even this:

```
var ctor = typeof(TOut).GetPrivateConstructor();
    if (ctor != null) // can replace
    {
         var expr = Expression.New(ctor);
         expr.Update(node.Arguments);//<=====Exception in this line
         return expr;
    }
```

I will get the following error:

> Incorrect number of arguments for constructor

And if I use the following:

```
var ctor = typeof(TOut).GetPrivateConstructor();
if (ctor != null) // can replace
     return Expression.New(ctor);
```

I will miss the arguments!

**Update 2**

If I use it as:

```
var ctor = typeof(TOut).GetPrivateConstructor();
if (ctor != null) // can replace
{
   var expr = Expression.New(ctor);

   FieldInfo argementsField = expr.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "_arguments");
   argementsField.SetValue(expr, node.Arguments);

   expr.Update(node.Arguments);
   return expr;
}
```

The expression will be built, but will not be executed as it produces the following:

```
x => new MyType(MyProp = x.MyProp)
```

Which is incorrect again will produce the following error as expected:

> Incorrect number of arguments for constructor

Comment: can you add your ExpressionVisitor class to your post

Comment: @sayahimad ExpressionVisitor is a builtin class in .Net which resides in System.Linq.Expressions namespace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the return type of an expression<func<>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328693/changing-the-return-type-of-an-expressionfunc)

Comment: @johnny5 I have updated the question to show the differences between this question and the mentioned possible duplicate questions.

Comment: I have solved this problem and faced other problem. here is my solution and the new problem:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55730825/1666800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `MyType` looking like this

```
public class MyType
{
    public MyType(string myProp)
    {
        MyProp = myProp;
    }

    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

you can create a generic visitor:

```
public class MyVisitor<TIn, TOut> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Type funcToReplace;

    public MyVisitor()
    {
        funcToReplace = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TIn), typeof(object));
    }

    // this hack taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2483054/4685428
    // and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650895/4685428
    private static bool IsAnonymousType(Type type)
    {
        var markedWithAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(
          typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)).Any();
        var typeName = type.Name;

        return markedWithAttribute
          && typeName.StartsWith("<>")
          && typeName.Contains("AnonymousType");
    }

    protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node)
    {
        if (IsAnonymousType(node.Type))
        {
            var arguments = node.Arguments.Select(a => a.Type).ToArray();
            var ctor = typeof(TOut).GetConstructor(arguments);
            if (ctor != null) // can replace
                return Expression.New(ctor, node.Arguments);
        }
        return base.VisitNew(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != funcToReplace)
            return base.VisitLambda(node);

        var p = node.Parameters.First();
        var body = Visit(node.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(body, p);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Expression<Func<TypeOfX, object>> input = x => new {MyProp = x.MyProp};

var visitor = new MyVisitor<TypeOfX, MyType>();
var result = (Expression<Func<TypeOfX, MyType>>) visitor.Visit(input);
```

Some explanation:

In `VisitNew` we check that constructor is belong to anonymous type. If so we trying to search in `TOut` type for constructor with same arguments. On success we replace anonymous type constructor with constructor from `TOut`

Comment: I think from the question the Object Represents the TOut, so chances are you just want to use a Convert

Comment: @johnny5 _constructor that takes in both arguements_ I did not get what your mean, sorry. My code replace a call to anonymous constructor with a call to defined constructor (if it exists). I've tested it and it's works on OP input. Could you please post another answer with `Expression.Convert` example? I would be glad to learn something new about Expressions

Comment: @alekz no your right my fault, I though the OP wanted to cast an expression like described in the title

Comment: @AleksAndreev I have updated mu question and added some more information. Thank for your time and solution

Comment: @AleksAndreev Thanks to your help I have solved this problem and faced other problem. here is my solution and the new problem:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55730825/1666800