# Variable 'x.Sub' of type 'SubType' referenced from scope '' but it is not defined error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, visitor-pattern

Check this fiddle for the error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tlz4Qg

I have two classes like this:

```
public class ParentType{
    private ParentType(){}

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public SubType Sub { get; protected set; }
}

public class SubType{
    private SubType(){}

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

I am going to transform a multilevel anonymous expression to a multilevel non-anonymous expression. To achieve this I have an expression like the below-mentioned one:

```
x => new
{
   x.Id,
   Sub = new
   {
      x.Sub.Id
   }
}
```

To achieve that goal, I have transformed it to an expression like this:

```
x => new ParentType()
{
   Id = x.Id,
   Sub = new SubType()
   {
      Id = x.Sub.Id
   },
 }
```

But when I call `Compile()` method, I get the following error:

> Variable 'x.Sub' of type 'SubType' referenced from scope '' but it is not defined

Here is my visitor class:

```
public class ReturnTypeVisitor<TIn, TOut> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Type funcToReplace;
    private ParameterExpression currentParameter;
    private ParameterExpression defaultParameter;
    private Type currentType;

    public ReturnTypeVisitor() => funcToReplace = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TIn), typeof(object));

    protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node)
    {
        if (!node.Type.IsAnonymousType())
            return base.VisitNew(node);

        if (currentType == null)
            currentType = typeof(TOut);

        var ctor = currentType.GetPrivateConstructor();
        if (ctor == null)
            return base.VisitNew(node);

        NewExpression expr = Expression.New(ctor);
        IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings = node.Members.Select(x =>
        {
            var mi = currentType.GetProperty(x.Name);

 //if the type is anonymous then I need to transform its body
                if (((PropertyInfo)x).PropertyType.IsAnonymousType())
                {
 //This section is became unnecessary complex!
 //
                    var property = (PropertyInfo)x;

                    var parentType = currentType;
                    var parentParameter = currentParameter;

                    currentType = currentType.GetProperty(property.Name).PropertyType;

                    currentParameter = Expression.Parameter(currentType, currentParameter.Name + "." + property.Name);

 //I pass the inner anonymous expression to VisitNew and make the non-anonymous expression from it
                    var xOriginal = VisitNew(node.Arguments.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == property.PropertyType) as NewExpression);

                    currentType = parentType;
                    currentParameter = parentParameter;

                    return (MemberBinding)Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
                }
                else//if type is not anonymous then simple find the property and make the memberbinding
                {
                    var xOriginal = Expression.PropertyOrField(currentParameter, x.Name);
                    return (MemberBinding)Expression.Bind(mi, xOriginal);
                }
        });

        return Expression.MemberInit(expr, bindings);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != funcToReplace)
            return base.VisitLambda(node);

        defaultParameter = node.Parameters.First();

        currentParameter = defaultParameter;
        var body = Visit(node.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(body, currentParameter);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>> Transform<Tin, Tout>(this Expression<Func<Tin, object>> source)
    {
        var visitor = new ReturnTypeVisitor<Tin, Tout>();
        var result = (Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>>)visitor.Visit(source);
        return result;// result.Compile() throw the aforementioned error
    }
```

Here is the extension methods used inside my Visitor class:

```
public static ConstructorInfo GetPrivateConstructor(this Type type) =>
            type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);

// this hack taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2483054/4685428
// and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650895/4685428
public static bool IsAnonymousType(this Type type)
{
 var markedWithAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), inherit: false).Any();
 var typeName = type.Name;

 return markedWithAttribute
               && (typeName.StartsWith("<>") || type.Name.StartsWith("VB$"))
               && typeName.Contains("AnonymousType");
}
```

**Update**

Here is the .Net Fiddle link for the problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tlz4Qg

**Update**

I have removed the extra codes that seems to be out of the problem scope.

Comment: Can't really see what's wrong without context.  Can you create a **[mcve]** that we can run, showing a simple input and expected output?  Forget about your visitor class - just data and a method.

Comment: @Archer I have updated the question and added some details to easily reproduce the issue. Thank you

Comment: @VahidFarahmandian Please include extensions methods like `GetPrivateConstructor` and `IsAnonymousType`. Also check lambda used in `node.Members.Select`: it should not compile because not all code path have a return.

Comment: @AleksAndreev I ahve updated the question and added the extension methods and correct the compile error

Comment: @Archer I have added the fiddle link for problem. Thank you

Comment: @AleksAndreev I have added the fiddle link for problem. Thank you

Comment: @Nkosi I have corrected the question, that was miss-typed error. Thank you for comment, however it was not the cause of error. Please check the fiddle link too.

Comment: @VahidFarahmandian I knew that. I was just bringing it to your attention to clarify the typo

Comment: It's not really clear to me how you expect your current code to work - but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using `Expression.Parameter`, as you're not really trying to create a new parameter. You want the parameter expression in the result to look the same as the parameter expression in the original, right? So I think you're going about things the wrong way there.

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact what I am trying to do is, to transform a multilevel anonymous expression to a multilevel non-anonymouse expression. I am agree with you that I have confused myself with the problem in Visitor class, but I do not know how to get rid of it

Comment: Without understanding how your current code tries to work, it's very hard to help - I'd basically start from scratch. If you can work out why you were creating parameter expressions at all, and add comments to your code, that would help explain things.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your support, I think I need to find a simple and better way to describe the requirement and problem. I am going to edit the question and make it as simple as possible and make it easy to understand. I will inform you, once I update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem in question is the line

```
currentParameter = Expression.Parameter(currentType, currentParameter.Name + "." + property.Name);
```

inside `VisitNew` method.

With your sample, it creates a new parameter called "x.Sub", so if we mark the parameters with `{}`, the actual result is

```
Sub = new SubType()
{
    Id = {x.Sub}.Id
},
```

rather than expected

```
Sub = new SubType()
{
    Id = {x}.Sub.Id
},
```

In general you should not create new `ParameterExpression`s except when remapping lambda expressions. And all newly created parameters should be passed to `Expression.Lambda` call, otherwise they will be considered "not defined".

Also please note that the visitor code has some assumptions which doesn't hold in general. For instance

```
var xOriginal = Expression.PropertyOrField(currentParameter, x.Name);
```

won't work inside nested `new`, because there you need access to a member of the `x` parameter like `x.Sub.Id` rather than `x.Id`. Which is basically the corersonding expression from `NewExpression.Arguments`.

Processing nested lambda expressions or collection type members and LINQ methods with expression visitors requires much more state control. While converting simple nested anonymous `new` expression like in the sample does not even need a `ExpressionVisitor`, because it could easily be achieved with simple recursive method like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Tin, Tout>> Transform<Tin, Tout>(this Expression<Func<Tin, object>> source)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Tin, Tout>>(
        Transform(source.Body, typeof(Tout)),
        source.Parameters);
}

static Expression Transform(Expression source, Type type)
{
    if (source.Type != type && source is NewExpression newExpr && newExpr.Members.Count > 0)
    {
        return Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(type), newExpr.Members
            .Select(m => type.GetProperty(m.Name))
            .Zip(newExpr.Arguments, (m, e) => Expression.Bind(m, Transform(e, m.PropertyType))));
    }
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Thats really amazing and works perfectly, however I have some challenges with collection type members, which I am working on it to overcome this challenge.

Comment: Do you have any idea about transforming this too?: Tests = x.SubType.Tests.Select(u => new {Y = new {u.Id})

Comment: If it's a simple `Select`, may be not that big deal. But if it could be virtually everything, e.g. other LINQ operators before and/or after `Select`, than it's much more complicated because you have to change the lambdas return or input types, LINQ methods generic type arguments (binding to different method definitions) etc. - all that with proper state machine. Basically all AutoMapper and similar are doing with predefined mappings.

Comment: No, it is just a simple SELECT as commented in aforementioned comment.

Comment: Can you please post another (follow up) question with the new scenario because the comment space is limited, and it definitely needs some code :)