# Argument types do not match Transforming anonymous Expression<Func<T,U>> to non anonymous Expression<Func<T,U>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, visitor-pattern

Imagine that we have three classes like this:

```
public class ParentType {
    private ParentType() {}

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public SubType Sub { get; protected set; }
}

public class SubType{
    private SubType(){}

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public ICollection<ColSubType> ColSubs{get; protected set;}
}

public class ColSubType{
    private ColSubType(){}

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public SubType SubType { get; set; }
}
```

I have an anonymous Expression like this:

```
x => new
{
   x.Id,
   Sub = new
   {
      x.Sub.Id,
      ColSubs = x.Sub.ColSubs.Select(u=> new {
             u.Id
      }).ToList()
   }
}
```

I need to transform it to a non anonymous Expression like this:

```
x => new ParentType()
{
   Id = x.Id,
   Sub = new SubType()
   {
      Id = x.Sub.Id,
      ColSubs = x.Sub.ColSubs.Select(u=> new ColSubs(){
             Id = u.Id
      }).ToList()
   }
}
```

Thanks to @IvanStoev's answer to this question: [Variable 'x.Sub' of type 'SubType' referenced from scope '' but it is not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55730825/1666800) I am able to transform the simple Expressions, but when I add `x.Sub.ColSubs.Select(...)` I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is a code you need to add to the recursive `Transform` method which handles **exactly** that scenario, i.e. detect `Select` method, transform the `selector` argument, modify the `TResult` generic type argument of the `Select` and call it with the new `selector`, and finally call `ToList` in case the destination is not `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
if (source.Type != type && source is MethodCallExpression call && call.Method.IsStatic
    && call.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable) && call.Method.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select))
{
    var sourceEnumerable = call.Arguments[0];
    var sourceSelector = (LambdaExpression)call.Arguments[1];
    var sourceElementType = sourceSelector.Parameters[0].Type;
    var targetElementType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var targetSelector = Expression.Lambda(
        Transform(sourceSelector.Body, targetElementType),
        sourceSelector.Parameters);
    var targetMethod = call.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        .MakeGenericMethod(sourceElementType, targetElementType);
    var result = Expression.Call(targetMethod, sourceEnumerable, targetSelector);
    if (type.IsAssignableFrom(result.Type)) return result;
    return Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.ToList), new[] { targetElementType },
        result);
}
```