# Change return type of Expression<Func<,>> with value types

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I have defined an `Expression<Func<TSource, T>>` whose return type (`T`) is an `enum`. I am using this and other similar expressions for projecting and filtering items with entity framework.

I would also like to be able to use this expression within a context where only numeric values are expected and in that case pass / convert the expression as `Expression<Func<TSource, T>>` where `T` is of type `int?`.

### What I have tried

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42016653/6038796) shows how to use the Visitor pattern to change the return type between `object` and a reference type which works fine. It does however not work when trying the same thing with value types.

```
public class ReturnTypeVisitor<TSource, TReturnValue> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource), typeof(TReturnValue));
        return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(TSource))
            return Expression.Property(Visit(node.Expression), node.Member.Name);

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}

[Test]
public void CanChangeFuncReturnTypeFromEnumToInt()
{
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, MyEnum?>> enumExpression = p => p.EnumValue;
    Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>> intExpression = (Expression<Func<MyEntity, int?>>)new ReturnTypeVisitor<MyEntity, int?>().Visit(enumExpression);
    
    var value = intExpression.Compile().Invoke(new MyEntity { EnumValue = MyEnum.One });

    value.Should().Be(1);
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public MyEnum? EnumValue { get; set; }
}
```

### Exception

```
System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[Xxx.Filtering.ReturnTypeVisitorVerifications+MyEnum]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Type delegateType, Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Type delegateType, Expression body, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Filtering.ReturnTypeVisitor`2.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node) in xxx\ReturnTypeVisitor.cs:line 11
   at Xxx.Filtering.ReturnTypeVisitorVerifications.CanChangeFuncReturnTypeFromEnumToInt() in yyy\ReturnTypeVisitorVerifications.cs:line 26
```

### The question

How can I change the `ReturnTypeVisitor` to work with value types, or is there another way of converting the expression?

Comment: This isn't because of value-types; it is because you need to do more than just change the type. You can't just change between `int?` and `MyEnum?` naively; you effectively need to reconstruct like  (sorry, link too long...)

Comment: like in here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKBQBgAIUMA6AGQEsA7AR1IFEAPABwTiikoHtqoBuXLhQBmYmkIBhQgG9chBcQwA2YgBZCAFW4BZAJ4NqAVzAAKAJTzFcnIruFmbDl14AeFAFZX+wzEow9ABpCH2MwAH4APkjCODDHdk4eakIAXkIWNJiWRjCANQgAGyM4QVt7BSsFAF8qpVUUDW0ASWoYETQLOpsKhQTnZPcvUL8A4JoYKJiJ/qTeNIyswlMJ8PMcwxMC4tK62px90ViwkIMw3B7FAHlqOAWMQLrNAHduBbRcfeExdFPffz0FzqR1CJnCDnyRRKskIAHM4DB+IQoAikft9kA=

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. The above works for reference types (for example object -> SomeClass). Could you elaborate on why it isn't possible for value types?

Comment: because a reference cast is much simpler than a "lifted" nullable-T cast

Comment: That seems like a lot of work - couldn't you just rebuild the `LambdaExpression` by surrounding the body with `Expression.Convert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extension method to convert the result of the original lambda:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static Expression<Func<TSource,int?>> ConvertToNullableInt<TSource, TEnum>(this Expression<Func<TSource,TEnum>> src)
        => Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource,int?>>(Expression.Convert(src.Body, typeof(int?)), src.Parameters);
}
```

which you can then use like:

```
Expression<Func<Test,TestEnum>> f = t => t.e;
var g = f.ConvertToNullableInt();
```